# Explicit positioning a Pane

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to create a basic UML diagramming tool with JavaFX.

First I did this:

```
public class Asd extends Application {
    Double WINDOW_HEIGHT = (double) 400;
    Double WINDOW_WIDTH = (double) 800;
    Double RECTANGLE_DEFAULT_HEIGHT = (double) 50;
    Double RECTANGLE_DEFAULT_WIDTH = (double) 100;


    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        final Pane root = new Pane();
        Rectangle background = new Rectangle(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT,
                Color.WHITE);
        root.getChildren().add(background);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root, WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        // On window click
        root.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
                Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
                rect.setX(mouseEvent.getX());
                rect.setY(mouseEvent.getY());
                rect.setWidth(RECTANGLE_DEFAULT_WIDTH);
                rect.setHeight(RECTANGLE_DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
                rect.setFill(null);
                rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                root.getChildren().add(rect);
            }
        });
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

With that, I can draw a rectangle (that would represent a UML Class) in the exact point I click.

Now I want to add text. If instead of

```
root.getChildren().add(rect);
```

I do

```
Text text = new Text("mockText");
StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
stackPane.getChildren().addAll(rect, text);
root.getChildren().add(stackPane);
```

the text is placed in the center of the rectangle, but all rectangles are positioned at coordinates (0,0)

So, any way to change the position of each StackPane? Or any alternative to add text to the rectangles directly without using StackPane?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, got it. Layout elements have methods setLayoutX & setLayoutY that can be used in cases like this one, so I don't need anymore Rectangle.setX/setY & finally the handle method should be:

```
public void handle(MouseEvent mouseEvent) {
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();
    rect.setWidth(RECTANGLE_DEFAULT_WIDTH);
    rect.setHeight(RECTANGLE_DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
    rect.setFill(null);
    rect.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
    Text text = new Text("mockText");
    StackPane stackPane = new StackPane();
    stackPane.getChildren().addAll(rect, text);
    stackPane.setLayoutX(mouseEvent.getX());
    stackPane.setLayoutY(mouseEvent.getY());
    root.getChildren().add(stackPane);
}
```